# Something is wrong in my SpringAOP Demo code with a null

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am learning Spring AOP.I just write some very simple code to have a try.I cannot understand why the **"re"** is null after calling the ControllerImpl's login method in my test code.

I only know a few knowledge about how Spring AOP works,maybe it's the reason why I cannot understand the failure.

Maybe you can run the test in AopTest.java.I am using the newest STS as my IDE.

I used STS to debug my code,but Spring AOP using dynamic proxy,so I cannot see the details.

You will see something like this "result = null":

[Click to see my test output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoJoB.png)

[This is my test code.At Github.](https://github.com/hit-lacus/DamselKnight/blob/master/Sample/src/test/java/hit/lacus/damsel/sample/aop/test/AopTest.java)

```
public class AopTest {

@Autowired
private Controller_ con;

@Test
public void testControllerWithCorrectUid(){
    System.out.println("==============================================");
    String re = con.login(123);
    System.out.println("result = " + re);
    System.out.println("==============================================");
    assertEquals("success",re);
}

@Test
public void testControllerWithWrongUid(){
    System.out.println("==============================================");
    String re = con.login(456);
    System.out.println("result = " + re);
    System.out.println("==============================================");
    assertEquals("fail",re);
}

}
```

Comment: This question is currently badly asked, because it does not contain the relevant code but only links to it. Here the relevant part is the around advice. Please add it to the question for future reference - not downvoted because I assume you did not know that the problem was there :-)

Comment: Now I understand what you mean.Last month I just started to learn how to ask question in StackOverflow.And I really **appreciate** your help.(I have to say that English is not my mother tongue,so maybe I cannot express myself clearly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer in two parts:

*I used STS to debug my code,but Spring AOP using dynamic proxy,so I cannot see the details.*: wrong. First, you could load the sources from Spring framework and single step its inner classes until it reaches yours, but you can just put breakpoints in you advice and advised methods.

Then the actual cause of you controller returning null when none of its return values are. After seeing your output, I assume that the `login` method did return a not null string value, probably `success`. But your around advice failed to pass it back to caller.

Spring reference manual states that (emphasize mine):

> The invoke() method **should return** the invocation’s result: the **return value of the join point**.

and even gives an example:

```
public class DebugInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before: invocation=[" + invocation + "]");
        Object rval = invocation.proceed();
        System.out.println("Invocation returned");
        return rval;
    }
}
```

But your around advice is a `void` method and and such the caller gets nothing and sees a null. The advice should be:

```
@Around("action()")
public Object logWarn(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) { 
    Object ret;
    System.out.println("AroundAdvice -> LogAspectImpl ");   
    try {
        ret = jp.proceed(); // store the return value of the advised method
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("AroundAdvice -> LogAspectImpl ");
    return ret;  // and pass it back to caller
}
```

Comment: Without your answer,I cannot understand what happened.
Thanks for your help.